# wp_update_term not creating new unique slug

Tags: terms, slug

I want the slug to be recreated every time the term name is updated so it accurately reflects the name.

```
wp_update_term(10, 'artists', array('name' => 'my new name'));
```

The documentation for [wp_update_term](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_term) says:

> If the 'slug' argument in $args is missing, then the 'name' in $args will be used. It should also be noted that if you set 'slug' and it isn't unique then a WP_Error will be passed back. If you don't pass any slug, then a unique one will be created for you.

The slug, which already exists and is already set to `"my-old-name"` does not update to 
`"my-new-name"` when I run the above function.

Is this intended?  Do I need to manually code the slug generation and change it myself in the arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are running into trouble with these lines in `wp_update_term()`:

> ```
> 3287          // Merge old and new args with new args overwriting old ones.
> 3288          $args = array_merge($term, $args);
> ```
>
> https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1.1/src/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L3287

The array passed in gets merged with the data already in the DB.

Set your slug explicitly:

```
$nname = 'my new name';
wp_update_term(
  10, 
  'artists', 
  array(
    'name' => $nname,
    'slug' => sanitize_title($nname)
  )
);
```

`sanitize_title()` is the same function used by `wp_update_term()` to convert the name to a slug:

> ```
> 3309          $empty_slug = false;
> 3310          if ( empty( $args['slug'] ) ) {
> 3311                  $empty_slug = true;
> 3312                  $slug = sanitize_title($name);
> 3313          } else {
> 3314                  $slug = $args['slug'];
> 3315          }
> ```
>
> https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1.1/src/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L3312

That won't automatically prevent duplicate terms though. The `wp_insert_term()` function uses `wp_unique_term_slug()` instead.

> ```
> 2844          $slug = wp_unique_term_slug( $slug, (object) $args );
> ```
>
> https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1.1/src/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L2844

So using that in lieu of `sanitize_title()` in the code above should do the trick.

Comment: what if said slug already exists?  Does sanitize_title check that? ( aka I would prefer if it adds a 2 ).  Also, what would happen if I passed a blank slug in?  I will try this when I get a chance, thank you!

Comment: @JacobRaccuia : see the edit. I believe-- untested but based on reading the code-- that if you pass a blank slug the system will attempt to use the `name` argument.

Comment: So after some testing, it does indeed look like using 'slug' => '' will call upon wp_unique_term_slug.     I appreciate the long and thoughtful answer!