# How to preserve edits to Name or Slug of term when using wp_update_term on save?

Tags: functions, custom-taxonomy, hooks, terms

I am trying to insert content into a term's `description` field on save.

```
// insert stuff into description field of taxonomy
function insert_taxonomy_content( $term_id, $tt_id, $taxonomy ){
    // only insert content on certain taxonomies
    if ( $taxonomy === 'some_custom_taxonomy' ){

         // unhook this function so it doesn't loop infinitely
         remove_action('edit_term', 'insert_taxonomy_content');

         $content = "Some Content";
         $update_args = array(
             'description' => $content,
         );

         // update the post, which calls save_post again
         wp_update_term( $term_id, $taxonomy, $update_args );

         // re-hook this function
         add_action('edit_term', 'insert_taxonomy_content');
     }
 }
add_action('edit_term', 'insert_taxonomy_content', 10, 3);
```

The adding of the content works, but now I can't change the title of an existing term anymore. I also can't add a new term.

I think this is pointing me in the right direction: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/183852/10595

> The array passed in gets merged with the data already in the DB.

So how could I capture a new title and/or slug entered into the Name / Slug field to pass it on to `wp_update_term`?

I also tried this as per [cjbj's suggestion](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/239521/10595):

```
// insert stuff into description field of taxonomy
function insert_taxonomy_content( $term_id, $taxonomy ){
    // only insert content on certain taxonomies
    if ( $taxonomy === 'some_custom_taxonomy' ){

         // unhook this function so it doesn't loop infinitely
         remove_action('edit_terms', 'insert_taxonomy_content');

         $content = "Some Content";
         $update_args = array(
             'description' => $content,
         );

         // update the post, which calls save_post again
         wp_update_term( $term_id, $taxonomy, $update_args );

         // re-hook this function
         add_action('edit_terms', 'insert_taxonomy_content');
     }
 }
add_action('edit_terms', 'insert_taxonomy_content', 10, 2);
```

This lets me edit titles and slugs again, but now the `description` does not get updated.

Comment: Pitty that didn't work. But it does show that doing two updates in a row leads to the first one getting lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, thanks to cjbj I finally found the correct answer! I needed to use [`edited_term`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/edited_term/) instead of `edit_term`. Very subtle difference. `edited_term` fires after a term has been saved.

```
// insert stuff into description field of taxonomy
function insert_taxonomy_content( $term_id, $tt_id, $taxonomy ){
    // only insert content on certain taxonomies
    if ( $taxonomy === 'some_custom_taxonomy' ){

         // unhook this function so it doesn't loop infinitely
         remove_action('edited_term', 'insert_taxonomy_content');

         $content = "Some Content";
         $update_args = array(
             'description' => $content,
         );

         // update the post, which calls save_post again
         wp_update_term( $term_id, $taxonomy, $update_args );

         // re-hook this function
         add_action('edited_term', 'insert_taxonomy_content');
     }
 }
add_action('edited_term', 'insert_taxonomy_content', 10, 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`edit_term`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/edit_term/) hook fires "**after** a term has been updated, but before the term cache has been cleaned". So every time you update a term you fire a function that updates the term again, but only its description. I haven't tested this, but I could imagine that somewhere in this process WP looses the first update and thinks the second update is the only one that matters.

Anyway, I suggest you try the [`edit_terms`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/edit_terms) hook, which fires **before** the term is being updated. In that way, your update doesn't interrupt the regular update process.

**UPDATE**

This may become a bit of a guessing game, but there are a couple more hooks in [`wp_update_term`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_term/) that you may try: `edited_terms`, `edit_term_taxonomy` and `edited_term_taxonomy`.

The point remains, however, that you are calling `wp_update_term` halfway inside `wp_update_term`. That function manipulates the global variable `$wpdb`. So the database is first changed by the first part of the outer call, then by the inner call (your function) and then again by the second part of the outer call.

Perhaps a better course of action would be to ditch the call to `wp_update_terms` in your function. Instead you could try to update the description immediately using `$wpdb->update`, so no other manipulation of the database takes place inside your hook function. I couldn't test this, but tracing how `wp_update_terms` handles the description it would be something like this:

```
$description = "Some Content";
$wpdb->update( $wpdb->term_taxonomy, compact( 'description' ));
```

Comment: See my update, still no luck.

Comment: Thanks for helping me in the right direction. So many hooks with similar names!